# Persisting Errors between Controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a question about ASP .Net MVC.
I Have a email registration form in my master page (toolbar), it has a text field for email and a button that send the email to my Home Controller.

The problem I am having is that if I navigate to a page in a different controller and I click submit to submit my email and if that email has errors then I add an error to ModelState.Errors and then redirect to the original Page (I have the original page in a hidden field in my form, so I know where to redirect), as you might have already noticed the error gets lost because in the other controller we have a completely different ModelState.

If there are no errors the email gets saved and the user is sent to a completed page successfully.

I first thought I could save the Errors in TempData and then check to see if it has value somewhere in a action filer or base Controller class and add it to the new Controller ModelState.

I would like to know if there are any other way or better way or even if sending the error in TempData is a good practice at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The usual pattern of a POST action is the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(MyModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // if there were some validation errors redisplay the form so that
        // the user can fix them
        return View(model);
    }

    // At this stage we know that the model is valid => we may try do some
    // processing on it:
    if (!Repository.TryDoSomeProcessing(model))
    {
        // Something wen wrong with our processing => redisplay the form
        // to inform the user of this
        ModelState.AddModelError("foo", "bar");
        return View(model);
    }

    // at this stage we know that the processing succeeded => we may redirect
    // there will no longer be error messages. We could at maximum use TempData
    // to store some success message:
    TempData["message"] = "Thank you for submitting!";
    return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```

Of course if you violate this pattern and want to redirect by persisting errors, etc... you are on your own. I have seen people struggling with TempData, Sessions, Cache, ... to persistent errors between redirects. I prefer to leave those techniques without a comment.

Comment: Thank you, I should probably use Ajax and save the hassle then !?

Comment: @Raha, yeah, AJAX could save lots of hassles.

Answer (score 0):

I have had great success using `TempData` to save the `ModelState` between redirects, and would absolutely recommend it!

The MvcContrib project has a good helper that makes it easy to save and restore the ModelState to TempData using Action filters.

However, for our projects we wanted manual control, so we created extensions methods for `TempData` so that we could use the following code:

```
TempData.SaveModelState(ModelState);
return Redirect...;
```

And to restore:

```
TempData.RestoreModelState(ModelState);
```

This way, our website never renders a view from an invalid POST, it always redirects to a GET.